# Populate list view

Tags: android, mysql, listview

I am developing a final year project and I am stuck at a point. I have to retrieve names of doctors from my database (MySQL database) and show it in a list view. I was able to establish a connection with the server and retrieve values, but when I tried to show the values in a list view, the application crashed!

I tried the same example given in *[Hello, Views, List View][4]*.

It works for a predefined array like

```
private String lv_arr[]={"Android","iPhone","BlackBerry","AndroidPeople"};
```

but for a string array retrieved from the database it shows a run time exception. Is there any way I can achieve this?

```
package com.proj;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.widget.*;
import android.app.ListActivity;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class proj extends ListActivity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public int n=0;
    public int t=0;
    public int i=0;

    public String name[]=new String[30];
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources
        // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.
        TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);;
        //Call the method to run the data retrieval
        getServerData(KEY_121);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,
                       android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, name));
    }

    public static final String KEY_121 = "http://10.0.2.2/doc.php"; //I use my real IP address here.

    private String getServerData(String returnString) {
        InputStream is = null;

        String result = "";
        //The year data to send.
        ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("year","1970"));

        //HTTP post
        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(KEY_121);
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            is = entity.getContent();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());
        }

        //Convert response to string
        try{
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
            is.close();
            result=sb.toString();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
        }
        //Parse JSON data
        try {
            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
            {
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                n=jArray.length();
                name[i]=json_data.getString("name");

                //Get an output to the screen
                returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            }
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return returnString;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code as well as logcat error....

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res  /android"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      >
    <ListView  
         android:id="@+id/list"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         />
<TextView 
 android:id="@+id/tv" 
       android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
       android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="@string/hello"
       />
   </LinearLayout>

Comment: Are you getting values in name String array..?

Comment: And you can post your xml also inside the code only...so that others can read easily...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using

**1.)**

```
android:id="@+id/list"
```

inside the ListView, but if your extend an activity by ListActivity you have to use

```
android:id = "@android:id/list"
```

**2.)**

You return a `String[]` here, not `String`

```
private String[] getServerData(String returnString) {
    .......
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    name = new String[jArray.length()];
    for(i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
    {
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        name[i]=json_data.getString("name");
    }
    return name;
}
```

And in ArrayAdapter, do it like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, getServerData(KEY_121));
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

Comment: what are you getting in your names string array..?

Comment: chetan vivek and shivani...the 3 doctors

Comment: when i try to print them in text view...values are getting printed

Answer (score 0):

```
public String name[];

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    // Create a crude view - this should really be set via the layout resources
    // but since its an example saves declaring them in the XML.
    TextView txt=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);;
        ...
        ...

    try {
        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
        name[]=new String[jArray.length()];
        for(i=0;i<jArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            n=jArray.length();
            name[i]=json_data.getString("name");

            //Get an output to the screen
            returnString += "\n\t" + jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        }
    }
    catch(JSONException e)
    {
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error parsing data "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It seems that initializing `name[]` with a size of 30 may be too small.

Comment: nope tried it...incresed the size to 100 but still same issue